# PlUpload in Jquery UI Dialog Can't Click To Add Files

Tags: javascript, jquery, plupload

I have a PLUpload that I am launching in a jQueryUI modal dialog.  After launching in the dialog, PlUpload's drag-and-drop still works, but clicking to launch the file browser does not.

JsFiddle of below code.  The JsFiddle includes the jQuery and jQuery UI versions that my app is using:
http://jsfiddle.net/QqPLV/1/

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="add-file-link">Open Uploader As Dialog</a>

<div id="AddFilePopup" title="Add A File">
    <div id="drop-target">After opening in a dialog clicking here does nothing, but drag and drop in Chrome still works...</div>
    <div id="plupload-nohtml5">No runtime found, your browser doesn't support HTML5 drag &amp; drop upload.</div>
    <div id="plupload-filelist"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
  #drop-target {
      border: 3px dashed #CCC;
      text-align: center;
      color: #999;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding : 50px;
      cursor: pointer;
  }
  #debug {
      margin-top: 20px;
  }
  #plupload-debug {
      border : 1px Solid #600;
      padding : 5px;
      margin : 5px;
  }
```

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    $('#add-file-link').click(function () {
        $('#AddFilePopup').dialog({
            modal: true,
            width: 600
        });

        uploader.refresh();  //this fixes IE10 not being able to click to add files
        return false;
    });

    initPlUpload();
});


function initPlUpload() {
    uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
        runtimes: 'html5',
        drop_element: 'drop-target',
        browse_button: 'drop-target',
        max_file_size: '4mb',
        upload: "upload.php"
    });

    uploader.bind('Init', function (up, params) {
        if (uploader.features.dragdrop) {
            $('#plupload-nohtml5').hide();
        };
    });

    uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function (up, files) {
        for (var i in files) {
            $('#plupload-filelist').append('<div id="' + files[i].id + '">- ' + files[i].name + ' - ' + files[i].id + ' (' + plupload.formatSize(files[i].size) + ')</div>');
        }
    });

    uploader.init();
    }
```

I added the line

```
uploader.refresh();
```

to the click handler, and that fixed IE10, but Chrome still refuses to cooperate.  Even entering uploader.refresh(); into Chrome's console does not bring the uploader's browse capability back to life...

Edit: To remove some lines that were not required to reproduce the problem and made it harder to read.

Comment: You probably have noticed it already : the problem disappears when setting the dialog options to modal: false The problem might be in the way dialog handles its overlay. Sorry I Can't be of more help

Comment: No, I hadn't noticed actually.  The popup will most definitely need to be in a modal state so I don't think I ever tried without it...but maybe if nobody knows a solution I can launch in non-modal form and then switch to model (which I have doubts about even being possible).  We'll see.  Thanks for the clue.  Must be something to do with the modal overlay blocking the click?

Comment: yes, I think the overlay interacts with the way plupload builds its layout, resulting in a blocked click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have the same problem and there is a tweak for that. It happens when you have HTML5 as upload engine, so to solve the trick you need to add a style:

```
.plupload{ z-index : 99999; }
```

or if you prefer on the fly....

```
$("div.plupload").css({"z-index":99999});
```

This should fix your problem.

Other thing is that you are destroying the uploader before you create the window, so it won't work. if you want to execute pluploader into the dialog, I advice you to use the parameter [open](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-open), so when the dialog initialize, it runs the behavior for pluploader on it.

Comment: Yes!  That was exactly it.  Thank you!
Here is an updated JSfiddle with the solution (see the #drop-target class in the CSS section):  http://jsfiddle.net/QqPLV/2/